# Remapping keys only one time in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I use a German keyboard layout and I'm trying to move some keys around.

There is one physical key on my keyboard that has: <kbd>ß</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ß</kbd>="?" and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ß</kbd>="\", (in the US-layout is the <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-/kbd>="_" key).</kbd>

I wish to move "ß" to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+ß="\" to "\" and disable <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ß</kbd>.

I tried this:

```
<^>!\::Return
<^>!s::Send ß
ß::Send \
```

This effectibly disables <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ß</kbd>="\" and makes <kbd>ß</kbd> input "\", but when I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> it also inputs "\".

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after further trying:

```
ß::\
<^>!s::Send ß
<^>!ß::Return
```